# get todays date as Timestamp format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, time, timestamp

I would like to get todays date in below format in python. How can I do that ? I need time part be 0 also.
Thank you.

```
Output should be labeled as timestamp:
Timestamp('2022-02-16 00:00:00') 

#what I tried but I need to have timestamp 
today=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the asnwer

```
  today=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
  ts = pd.Timestamp(today, tz=None)
  ts
  Output:
  Timestamp('2022-05-05 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```py
today=datetime.today().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

It seems that today also gives you the the time, but you can replace the Values to get

```
'2022-05-05 00:00:00'
```